# Datatable hide and show rows based on a button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symfony, datatables

So I have this datatable that is generated by php dynamically once. But once it's loaded, I don't want to reload the whole table since there's only a small javascript if statement that I am doing. When you press the button, I compare a data attribute that is on my tr. If it doesn't fit, I'd like to hide them, else, I'd like to show them. So here is what I tried so far.

HTML

```
    <div style="margin: 30px 0;">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="myClientButton">Voir mes clients seulements</button>
    </div>
    <table id="advancedSearchTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Profile</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for entity in entities %}
                <tr data-user="{{ entity.user.id }}" class="values">
                    <td>{{ entity }}</td>
                    <td>{{ entity.mainphone }}</td>
                    <td>{{ entity.email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ entity.tagline }}</td>
                    <td>{{ entity.createdDate|date('d-m-Y') }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{ path('clients_show', {id: entity.id}) }}" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a></td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The Loop is made in Symfony 2 (Using Twig Template, if you don't understand it it doesn't really matter) all you have to understand is that the attribute on "data-user" is created by PHP and that every entry of my database is going in this loop.

Then, in jQuery I have this:

```
<script>
$('#advancedSearchTable').DataTable(
    {
        "language": {
              "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-   ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/French.json"
                    },
               responsive: true
            });
  $('#myClientButton').on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('tr.values').show();
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('tr.values').each(function(){
            if ($(this).attr('data-user') != 5){
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

It works very well. The only problem is that the DataTable then is not "replacing itself". So, for example, if it has 25 pages, it keeps 25 pages and when you press on the "next table page" button, it refreshes the "table page" and things are not hidden anymore. I searched alot but I couldn't find a way. I really don't want to use ajax for this, since it only need to be filled once with value and then it will only have to hide or show depending on the button being active or not... Is it even possible using this jQuery plugin ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is because you're hiding client-side elements, and when you page the datatable it retrieves a new set of data which has no knowledge of what you've previously hidden.  Effectively you're trying to use server-side data with client-side filtering.

Comment: No i'm using client-side to hide. It clearly doesn't work because the data I hide are not calculated in the data table. For example, I hide half of the row but it still says"showing 20 of 150 items" (for example)... Coud I refresh the data table?

Comment: If you refresh the datatable, your rows will show again because the underlying data hasn't changed.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed possible, but you will need a different approach. Hiding rows with jQuery and not through dataTables itself is generally a bad idea, since dataTables is not aware of changes made to the original `<table>` element in DOM. There is no "somewhere-in-code-another-script-has-hidden-a-row"-event dataTables can hook into. That is why dataTables seems to "forget" changes, it is simply not aware of those changes, and the dataTables internals stay untouched.

So use a [**custom filter**](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) instead. The following small piece of code does what you want - hiding all rows having a `data-user` attribute different than `5`. It works across sorting and pagination. The last piece of code is an example of a reset-button.

```js
$("#hide").click(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
       function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
          return $(table.row(dataIndex).node()).attr('data-user') == 5;
       }
    );
    table.draw();
});    
$("#reset").click(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
    table.draw();
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/d5hre2ux/**

Comment: It's working perfectly but I couldn't find it accross the datatables documentation. Are you creating your own function to make it work or it's a function that already exist in Datatables ?

Comment: I can not make this work when there is two tables in the page. I would like to filter only one specific table, but both are filtered using this code. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Finally figured out that I had to add a check using `settings`, somethink like `if (settings.sTableId != "first_table") return true;`. I do not think there is any other way to solve this.

Comment: hi, sorry about being late to the party, but this code is not working for me :( The function simply won't be called. Any suggestions?

Comment: hey @Soham - any errors? There should be no version issues with this code, the only thing I can think about that possible should cause problems. You do realize that the filter functions is inserted in an lifo-array. So in the demo, if you click 2 times on hide you will need to click 2 times on reset ..?

Comment: Yes, I figured that out..the demo is not an issue. I cannot use it in my application tho. And no, no errors. The table simply does not move

Comment: hi, is there a way on how can i make automatically when loaded and not using any interaction like click?

Comment: @Jefsama, have you _tried_ to place `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push( `outside a click handler ...? This is what you should do. If you want a filter onload, simply add this filter before you instantiate the dataTable.

Comment: @davidkonrad, i've try it place at `preDrawCallback` but it doesn't work :(. am i doing it wrong? i use the give fiddle in testing.

Comment: @davidkonrad haha i thought would be very complicated to apply. thanks for a straight-forward answer XD

Comment: @davidkonrad - there's really no way to register 1 filter to 1 specific datatable? All tables receive the search function? That seems bizarre, making one function handle any/all tables needs. I have 4 tables on 1 page which need to be filtered...

Comment: @mmcrae, Unfortunately no, all filters are just stored in one global array and affects all tables on the page :( Agree that is inexpedient design, guess it never have been that big issue for the developer (but it is sometimes mentioned here on SO) A workaround need some programming, you can ask it as a question.

Comment: IMPORTANT : I believe you need to "$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop()" everytime before you push new filters in order to clear the earlier filters or you may end up with some unwanted results
Refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774746/reset-filtered-data-in-datatables

Answer (score 3):

According to this https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html it is possible to use `data` parameter to filter by any value shown on the table.

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
      function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
          return data[3] != "63";
        }
    );
    table.draw();
});
```

Comment: the `data` object would have basically the td cols, but OP wants to search by data- attributes on the tr's themselves. Which is why he needs to use the .node in the accepted answer