# DataTable filter with Date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables-1.10

I have 2 DataTable in one page for both DataTable I have added date range using

```
function filterDateRangeService(){
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(

                function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {                 
                    var dateStart = moment($("#fromDateSer").val(),"DD/MM/YYYY");
                    var dateEnd = moment($("#toDateSer").val(),"DD/MM/YYYY");

                    var evalDate= moment(data[5],"DD/MM/YYYY");
            console.log("dateStart +"+dateStart+" dateEnd "+dateEnd)

                // console.log("insidde")
                    if (evalDate >= dateStart && evalDate <= dateEnd) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                     }


            );

function filterDateRangePatient(){
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(

                    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {                 
                        var dateStart = moment($("#fromDate").val(),"DD/MM/YYYY");
                        var dateEnd = moment($("#toDate").val(),"DD/MM/YYYY");

                        var evalDate= moment(data[6],"DD/MM/YYYY");
                console.log("dateStart +"+dateStart+" dateEnd "+dateEnd)

                    // console.log("insidde")
                        if (evalDate >= dateStart && evalDate <= dateEnd) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {
                            return false;
                        }
                         }


                );
```

Both the function are called when respective checkbox is clicked. Problem is when I use date range for first function it filters the table for specific Date range, but When i try to filter the other table with 2nd function, only first function is called, i.e which ever function is called first only that function is called each time.
Calling function Using:

```
$('input[name="radioFilter"]').click(function(){        
                filterFunction();
            });
            $('input[name="radioFilterSer"]').click(function(){
                filterFunctionSer();
            });  
function filterFunction(){
//some functions..
filterDateRangePatient()
}
function filterFunctionSer(){
//some functions..
filterDateRangeService()
}
```

How to resolve this, Why is the first function which is called first is only being called later also, or any thing I am doing Wrong. Or is it because of return Statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about write single function with params and use it on both functions

```
function filterFunction(){
    //some functions..
    filterDateRange($("#fromDateSer").val(), $("#toDateSer").val(), 5)
}
function filterFunctionSer(){
    //some functions..
    filterDateRange($("#fromDate").val(), $("#toDate").val(), 6)
}
```

And the `filterDateRange` Function: (Updated: Added search `pop` function)

```
function filterDateRange(from, to, num){

    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();

    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {                 
        var dateStart = moment(from,"DD/MM/YYYY");
        var dateEnd = moment(to,"DD/MM/YYYY");

        var evalDate= moment(data[num],"DD/MM/YYYY");
        console.log("dateStart +"+dateStart+" dateEnd "+dateEnd);

        if (evalDate >= dateStart && evalDate <= dateEnd) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

It will work.

Comment: problem remains the same as which ever data table is filtered first will work.. so figured it out that filter function is keeping previous values stored some where to to filter again will have to clear the function and then call the function. for this we can use `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop()`. for more help check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774746/reset-filtered-data-in-datatables?rq=1).

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention it on the answer. Thanks. :)