# How do I hide an specific row in a datatables table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am programming a datatable that shows a list of users and I want to hide one of the rows after the user click on an action over an specific row.

```
function addUserToListForVacations(i) {

var user = usersInAGlobalVariable[i];

var table = $('#table-user-for-adding-vacations').DataTable();

table.row('#idRow').child.hide();
```

}

But it does not work

Comment: Can you provide a minimal runnable demo?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to do that

Comment: you can create on in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datatable hide and show rows based on a button click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086341/datatable-hide-and-show-rows-based-on-a-button-click-event)